# Export the custom templates I created

Tags: plsqldeveloper

How do I save/export the Templates that I created, so i can backup and share?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

*Templates* are just files on disks. They can be copied directly. By default, this is a subfolder *Template* of the folder in which *PL/SQL Developer* is installed.

This folder can be changed by setting *Files/Directories/Templates*.